# File.Move is not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
File.Move(@"/Resources/images/temp/" + xx, @"/Resources/images/event-images/" + newFile); // Try to move
```

The `File.Move` is also not working.How can I use it with relative paths ?

Could you tell me how to sort out above issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `File.Move is also not working`, is it throwing any error? `I cannot pick those files individually on my for loop`, whats the count in `provider.FileData`?

Comment: @ramiramilu It shows invalid path.I have used like this where still the same issue. `File.Move(@"~/Resources/images/temp/" + xx, @"~/Resources/images/event-images/" + newFile);`.Could you tell me how to use relative paths ?

Comment: @ramiramilu My uploaded file path where I gave as this.`var uploadFolder = "~/Resources/images/temp";`.It is working fine.But above one is not working.`it says no file on the above path`

Comment: Can you try like this - `string path = Server.MapPath("~"); File.Move(path + "\\Resources\\images\\temp\\" + xx, path + "\\Resources\\images\\event-images\\" + newFile);`

Comment: @ramiramilu  Yes,it's working.Can you put it as an answer ?

Comment: FYI: the `~` works only as "root of application" for paths that are processed (as path) through ASP.Net. File.Move goes directly to the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code -

```
var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");//hence WebApi
File.Move(path + "\\Resources\\images\\temp\\" + xx, path + "\\Resources\\images\\event-images\\" + newFile);
```